# Boolean operations on bit columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I perform boolean operations on columns of datatype bit? 
For example, how can I perform the logical "AND" of an entire column?

If the bits were cast as ints, then taking the min of the column would work as "AND" and checking if the sum is greater than zero would work for "OR", but is there any way to do it directly without the cast?

I would like to do something like

```
SELECT AND(bitColumn)
FROM tempTable
```

Comment: can you provide a psuedo code of what you want to achieve? What the you mean perform the logical AND of an entire column? It's a bit confusing

Comment: I have a column of data type bit. Bits can be interpreted as boolean values, 0 = false, 1 = true. I'd like to perform the operation of AND on the entire column, that is row1.bit && row2.bit && row3.bit...

Comment: You are talking about bitwise operations. And yes you will have to first convert it to an int. You can read more about bitwise operations in the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-operators-transact-sql

Comment: `Operand data type bit is invalid for sum operator.` So you need convert bit to integer so you can use group function SUM

Comment: You can write your own aggregated function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374709/custom-aggregate-function-concat-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to a number.  For `AND`:

```
SELECT CAST((CASE WHEN MIN(CAST(bitColumn as int)) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as BIT)
FROM tempTable;
```

For `OR`, use `MAX()`.

Answer (score 1):

No casting, no MIN:

```
SELECT IIF(1=ALL(SELECT bitColumn FROM tempTable),1,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no explicit function that will allow you to perform an AND or OR operation across all values stored in the table column. The simplest method is to simply cast the values to INT and use SUM or MAX values in combination with case statement.

You can use the bitwise operators to perform the same actions without performing any type conversion, however it is not any simpler.  I have included an example below mostly just for fun :)

```
-- ----------------------------------------------------
-- OR - Example
-- ----------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @LogicalOrResult BIT = 0; -- Initialize result as false.

-- Create sample data
SELECT * INTO #TableLogic
FROM    (
            SELECT 1 as ID, CAST(0 AS BIT) AS BitColumn UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 as ID, CAST(0 AS BIT) AS BitColumn UNION ALL
            SELECT 3 as ID, CAST(0 AS BIT) AS BitColumn UNION ALL
            SELECT 4 as ID, CAST(0 AS BIT) AS BitColumn UNION ALL
            SELECT 5 as ID, CAST(1 AS BIT) AS BitColumn
        ) Logic

-- OR all column values.
SELECT  @LogicalOrResult |= BitColumn
FROM    #TableLogic

-- Expected result: 1
SELECT @LogicalOrResult AS Result

DROP TABLE #TableLogic;

GO
-- ----------------------------------------------------
-- AND - Example
-- ----------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @LogicalOrResult BIT = 1; -- Initialize result as true.

-- Create sample data
SELECT * INTO #TableLogic
FROM    (
            SELECT 1 as ID, CAST(0 AS BIT) AS BitColumn UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 as ID, CAST(1 AS BIT) AS BitColumn UNION ALL
            SELECT 3 as ID, CAST(1 AS BIT) AS BitColumn UNION ALL
            SELECT 4 as ID, CAST(1 AS BIT) AS BitColumn UNION ALL
            SELECT 5 as ID, CAST(1 AS BIT) AS BitColumn
        ) Logic

-- AND all column values.
SELECT  @LogicalOrResult &= BitColumn
FROM    #TableLogic

-- Expected result: 0
SELECT @LogicalOrResult AS Result

DROP TABLE #TableLogic;
```