# Create custom T-SQL aggregate function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

I want to create a custom aggregate function like `SUM()`.

Can anyone help me how to create such an aggregate function in which we pass a column or row which returns a sum answer.

Comment: I think you can just write a UDF, as you would any other custom function.  But maybe tell us what you need to do; perhaps it can already be done with what SQL Server ships.

Comment: I know it already exist in SQL server but i need to learn that how create a aggregate function and type parameters and returns type also

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374709/custom-aggregate-function-concat-in-sql-server?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you can create [CLR User-Defined Aggregates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-user-defined-aggregates?view=sql-server-2017).