# T-SQL UDF aggregate function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, aggregate, user-defined-functions

Any guidance an producing a UDF aggregate function so that when used in a grouping query, it will return results based on how many values in the group.  I know the aggregate function needs to return an int but not sure how to pass the values (which vary) into it... Not a scalar type and  not sure if and how it would constitute a tabular type.

E.g how would I build a udf function for average...

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374709/custom-aggregate-function-concat-in-sql-server

Comment: "based on how many values in the group" - you mean `COUNT(*)`?

Comment: You can not use T-SQL to write custom aggregates (which is what "average" is)  - you can only write them using C# (or any other CLR language)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - you taught me something new today. I was recently trying to do what custom aggregates do using T-SQL and failed. I had never heard of these until your post.

Answer (score 0):

You can create UDF aggregates in c#.

A good start for reading is here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-user-defined-aggregates?view=sql-server-2017